# How to calculate Net Investment Income Tax: Expenses Allocation (IRS Form 8960)

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, state-income-tax

[In an answer to this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/136631/5993), @dave_thompson_085 quotes the section from the Form 8960 instructions dealing with line 9b - allocation of state tax investment expense.

Reading the answer and the instructions, I am confused as to whether I can take this deduction if I am using the Standard Deduction on the Form 1040. Is line 9b only applicable to Schedule A filers?

If I have $10,000 of NIIT and State Tax rate of 5%, but I do not itemize my deductions, can I claim a $500 investment expense on line 9b of Form 8960?